# Why won't my python function print the right thing?

Tags: function, printing

I was trying to make a python tic-tac-toe board but it woudn't print out:

```
AA=0;AB=0;AC=0;BA=0;BB=0;BC=0;CA=0;CB=0;CC=0
AAtext="AA";ABtext="AB";ACtext="AC";BAtext="BA";BBtext="BB";BCtext="BC";CAtext="CA";CBtext="CB"; CCtext="CC"
def board():
    def lines(A, B, C):
        print("|",A,"|",B,"|",C,"|")
    print("________________")
    lines(AAtext, ABtext, ACtext)
    print("|______________|")
    lines(BAtext, BBtext, BCtext)
    print("|______________|")
    lines(CAtext, CBtext, CCtext)
    print("|______________|")
print(board)
```

It turned out like:

```
<function board at 0x0000015798028E00>
```

I tried exiting out the print and changing the code, but it stayed the same

Comment: What language is this supposed to be? Please tag your question accordingly.  I suppose you want to call `print(board())` (note the extra parentheses). Currently you're not calling the function and just printing its address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to call function you must write this () too

correct answer is print(board())